# Java String Alignment

Tags: java, alignment

I am having some trouble with my project. The idea is, to create a program, which uses scanner to scan through .txt file, which contains number that indicates what style of alignment to use(1 = left align, 2 = right align & 3 = central), second number in input is the maximum length of line, third number the count of the words and then comes the text.

I made simple program to align the text to the left, but do not know how to do right align and central.

Here is the code for case 1(if you suggest some modifications or is there more elegant solution I'd be glad). Thank you very much!

```
import java.util*
public class Align {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int command = sc.nextInt();
    int sumOfChar = 0;
    boolean First = true;
    switch (command) {
        case 1:    
        int maximumLength = sc.nextInt();
        int numberOfWords = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++) {
            String word = sc.next();
            int a = word.length();
            sumOfChar = sumOfChar + a;
            if (First) {
                System.out.print(word);
                First = false;
            }
            else if (sumOfChar < maximumLength) {
                System.out.print(" "+word);
                sumOfChar++;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print(word);
                sumOfChar = a;
            }                                               
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is best if you make sure you get as far as you can before posting a question so that you can only ask about specific problems. Try some things, and once you are stuck on a specific task you should update this question to ask that. Try to avoid coming off as asking people to write your code for you. Good luck, have fun :).

Comment: Thank you :) it was not my intention to ask you to write your code for me, but am really lost here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to calculate how many spaces you need.

Second you need a method with will add the number of space required.

left align = add spaces after the word.

right align = add spaces before the word.

center align = add half the space before and half after.

Comment: Thank you, I get that logic. Right now I am looking into method, to count all of the letters and spaces to fit into specified long line, but am getting nowhere.

Comment: @javanoob you use `.length()` to count the letters as you have already done in your code, and the number of spaces is the `widthNeeded - string.length()`

Comment: Thank you, I got that, but it still doesn't put the remaining words in other lines, I mean, I don't know how to for example divide 20 words x 5 letters of text into 4 lines with space for 30 characters each...

Comment: @javanoob so you want 4 lines with 5 words each in 30 characters? make each word have a required length of 6, and println() every 5 words.

Answer (score 0):

Don't print out each word immediately if it fits. Instead, build a line representation (using a `StringBuilder`, for instance) and when the line is full (or you run out of input), you can then calculate how many leading spaces you need based on the alignment.

Comment: I have never used it but will look into StringBuilder. Thanks!